# Visualforce page to show all Chatter posts on contact and all related records

Tags: apex, chatter, related-list, chatter-feed-tracking

This code will give me all of the posts associated with that Contact but how can I also see all of the posts on related records (opportunities, leads, applications, cases, activities, etc) as well.

```
<chatter:feed entityId="{contactId}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed()` method to get feeds to display in a Visualforce page. The method is overloaded so choose a signature that works with record feeds.

See "Get Feed Elements from a Feed" on this page:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectapi_features_feeds_feed_elements.htm

Answer (score 0):

The chatter feed component only shows the feed for the one object.

You would have to query the FeedItem object for the ParentIds of whatever objects you want to see the feeds for. Then you would need to format those posts manually on a Visualforce page.